# Change color of selected TopTab border color

Tags: react-native-navigation

How can I change the color of this border.

I have tried using the following in options but that doesn't work.

```
topBar: {
 borderColor: "white"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which did try operation system ? ( Android / iOS ) *(I'm using PhpStorm because I'm Full-Stack developer, highly recommend.)* By selecting topBar you can go to the source with ctrl+b.

*Options.ts*

```
/**
   * Change the navbar border color
   * #### (Android specific)
*/
borderColor?: Color;
```

If not both, set the **borderHeight**. So like this; (*from my code*)

```
stack:{
    children:[
        {
            component:{
                name: 'app.Main.Shop',
                options:{
                    topBar:{
                        borderColor:'blue',
                        borderHeight:2
                    },
                },
            }
        }
    ],
    options: {..}
}
```

Result like this;

[image]